# I need Javascript code to capture IP address of the local system for Ipad devices

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am not able to capture ip address of ipad devices through JS code.This works fine in Windows system

Below is the code:

```js
var findIP = new Promise(r => {
  var w = window,
    a = new(w.RTCPeerConnection || w.mozRTCPeerConnection || w.webkitRTCPeerConnection)({
      iceServers: []
    }),
    b = () => {};
  a.createDataChannel("");
  a.createOffer(c => a.setLocalDescription(c, b, b), b);
  a.onicecandidate = c => {
    try {
      c.candidate.candidate.match(/([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/g).forEach(r)
    } catch (e) {}
  }
})
findIP.then(function(ip) {
  console.log(ip);
})
```

Comment: Are the calls compatible and allowed? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I think it's impossible, FYI https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46925857/get-the-client-ip-address-with-javascript-on-safari

Comment: @mplungjan I am able to capture for windows system, but when coming to Ipad device I get undefined value

Answer (score 0):

Under recent versions of IOS, Apple is intentionally obscuring the local IP address with the intention of making it hard to fingerprint a device. This is quite unfortunate, because it would be nice to know the IP address so that i could look for peers on the LAN.

The address that IOS returns os of the type:   9befcb75-3f5e-48f5-9201-744fc7ba406c.local

which is probably some random number that is useless.

Also it was not necessary to parse the candidate field, as there is a property in the candidate record called 'address' that normally has the IPv4 address as a string.

This code works on Mac desktop, and Android okay, but alas is useless on the iPad/iOS devices, which are rather numerous.

Answer (score 0):

here's a javascript function you can use to get IP address:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?jsoncallback=?', function (data) {
    console.log('ipAddress:', data.geoplugin_request);
});
```